# How to set node-data in list at specific index, unordered list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a method who sets node-data in list at specific index.
My node list is :

```
class Node:
    """
    Node class
    """

    def __init__(self, initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next = None

    def get_data(self):
        """
        Returns data
        """
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        """
        Gets next node
        """
        return self.next

    def set_data(self, newdata):
        """
        Sets current nodes data
        """
        self.data = newdata

    def set_next(self, newnext):
        """
        Sets next node
        """
        self.next = newnext
```

My unordered list class is some thing like this:

```
class UnorderedList:
    """
    Unordered list
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self, item):
        """
        Add item to list
        """
        temp = Node(item)
        temp.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = temp

    def set(self, index, newdata):
        """
        Set node-data in list at specific index
        """
        current = self.head
        for i in range(index):
            current = current.get_next()
        if current != None:
            temp = Node(newdata)
            temp.set_next(current.get_next())
            current.set_next(temp)
        else:
            raise("index out of range")

    def print_list(self):
        """
        Prints each item in list
        """
        # Traversera listan och gör en print() på varje element
        result = "["
        node = self.head
        if node != None:
            result += str(node.data)
            node = node.next
            while node:
                result += ", " + str(node.data)
                node = node.next
        result += "]"
        return result
```

It works very well when you try for example to add a item in the list like this:

```
myListTwo = UnorderedList()
myListTwo.add(4)
myListTwo.add(50)
myListTwo.add(6)
myListTwo.add(10)
myListTwo.add(60)

print(myListTwo.print_list())
```

than you get the list :

```
[60, 10, 6, 50, 4]
```

The problem is when i try to put a node-data in list at specific index i got this result :

```
myListTwo.set(2, 70)
print(myListTwo.print_list())
```

I got this result:

```
[60, 10, 6, 70, 50, 4]
```

You are 70 at index 3 not at index 2, any idea?

Comment: In `UnorderedList.set`, you're iterating over `index` nodes, and the new one would be  the `index + 1`th. Change your loop to `for i in range(index - 1):`

Comment: logical ;)  I do not know why I haven't thought about it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just as expected: you insert the new node **after** the ith node. So in your example, you correctly find the third node (`6`), and insert the node `70` immediately after it.

A simple fix could be:

```
def set(self, index, newdata):
    """
    Set node-data in list at specific index
    """
    current = self.head
    previous = None
    for i in range(index):
        previous = current
        current = current.get_next()
    if current != None:
        temp = Node(newdata)
        temp.set_next(current)
        if previous is None:
            self.head = temp
        else:
            previous.set_next(temp)
    else:
        raise("index out of range")
```

Comment: Wonderful! thank you for your help and the explaination!

Answer (score 0):

I change my loop to 
`for i in range(index - 1)`

Comment: Beware, it will not give expected result for index = 1

Comment: I just saw your answer! let met test it ;)